# Typescript super() call error

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs, grafana

I have a class

```
class CreateRuleTemplate extends PanelCtrl{
  constructor($scope, $injector, private $rootScope, private datasourceSrv){
    super($scope, $injector);
  }
}
```

PanelCtrl has

```
export class PanelCtrl {
  $scope: any;
  $injector: any;


  constructor($scope, $injector) {
    this.$injector = $injector;
    this.$scope = $scope;
  }
}
```

But on compiling with grunt-typescript I am getting "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target" error on the "super($scope, $injector);" line.

If I call just "super()" it compiles just fine.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code compiles. 
Calling a no-arg `super()` would otherwise make the app not compiling.
Make sure you cleaned the build and rebuild.

Comment: It should work. If you get a problem, it should be a TS7006 no implicit any warning instead. Please check your TypeScript version, etc. I'm using 2.5.3.